# How to convert hypothesis with "if then else" equality into its consequent using coq?

Tags: coq

How do I prove the following trivial theorem?

```ml
Theorem hmm : forall {A:Type} (b:bool) (x:A),
  (if b then Some x else None) = None -> b = false.
Proof.
intros A b x H.
inversion H. (* duplicates the hypothesis? *)
Fail assumption.
Admitted
```

I was expecting `inversion H` to infer that `b = false`, but instead it duplicates the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first do a proof by cases on b

```ml
Theorem hmm : forall {A:Type} (b:bool) (x:A),
  (if b then Some x else None) = None -> b = false.
Proof.
intros A b x H.
destruct b.
- inversion H.
- trivial.
Qed.
```